# Tailwind requires refresh to apply changes in Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I created a new project using Next.js 13 and added Tailwind the same way as I always do, but changes I made are not applied immediately, a full page refresh is required for them to work. I pasted my configs. Maybe I'm missing something.

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./layout/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
// some customization here, omitting
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["next/babel"],
    "plugins": []
  }
```

globals.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

and I include them in _app.tsx with `import '../styles/globals.css'`

Also, here are my dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.13.1",
    "@types/node": "18.11.9",
    "@types/react": "18.0.24",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.8",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "eslint": "8.26.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.0.2",
    "next": "13.0.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.2",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.18",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1"
  }
```

Comment: Import it in layout file too inside app directory

Comment: Please see https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43878.

Comment: Have you stopped your live server and ran `npm run dev`? It requires you to restart your server to get the live changes to begin working.

Answer (score 2):

Try this temporary fix.

```
content: [
  "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  "./layout/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  "!./node_modules", //  
],
```